# Is computeroxy trustworthy?

Tags: job-search, website, networking

I am wondering if computeroxy can be considered a "safe" website. I have received two emails from them in the past in my institutional email address without subscribing (one of them was a very long list of calls for papers if I recall correctly). Their website has no contact or ownership information other than a simple contact form and an email address, and the whois for their domain name (a .com; not linking to them directly in case they are a scam website) is hidden.

Looking for the name on Google shows some results that seem to support it is a scam but at the same time I do not consider them conclusive.

But today someone I know forwarded a new email from them to the mailing list of a student network. The forwarded message has an enormous list of links to their website with open positions in academia (graduate, postgraduate, senior...) and the non-representative non-random subset I picked had actual real offers (from existing institutions and with links to the offers at the institutions' websites). Since I am part of a team that prepares a newsletter for that student network but reaches a wider audience and includes a section of scholarships and job offers, I was wondering: is it safe to include a link to computeroxy or is it better to just forget about it?

(not quite sure about the tags I have used...)

Comment: I cannot say whether it is "safe" in general, but I know that I have received considerably more than two emails from them, regularly. No matter whether their intentions are good or bad, I consider them spammers.

Comment: According to their website, they get "1,400 views per advertisement monthly" while sending out 1,260,000 emails (630,000 people twice a month, it claims) per month, so that's roughly on the order of 0.1% response per ad per email sent out...so in other words, yes, they are a spam company. They even use words like "attracts the attention of...", and then proceed to call those people clients. Ew.

Comment: Ok. So maybe they are not a scam, but they can be considered a spam company indeed. What made me doubt was that Inria alumni and one school from the University of Barcelona have shared links to them on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/search?q=computeroxy). Probably not enough results, though.

Maybe what @BrianHall said using the numbers can be posted as an answer?